# Typescript: rewrite a fat arrow function a do not lose bare function signature check

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, reducers

In order to use AOT in Angular I need to rewrite all my functions / reducers to not use arrow functions:

> ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function

Reducer using ES6 style:

```
export const config: ActionReducer<ConfigModel> = (state: ConfigModel = null, {type, payload}: action.ResponseActions) => {
    switch (type) {
        case configAction.LOAD_SUCCESS:
            return ...;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Rewritten to *exported function* style:

```
export function config(state: ConfigModel = null, {type, payload}: action.ResponseActions) {
    switch (type) {
        case configAction.LOAD_SUCCESS:
            return ...;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

But I lost the type check: callable interfaces with a bare function signature.

`ActionReducer<ConfigModel>` is no more specified. How to specify the `config` reducer *implements* the `ActionReducer<ConfigModel>`?
Is it possible to specify that the function implements callable interface with a bare function?

ActionReducer (for the sake of completeness):

```
export interface ActionReducer<T, V extends Action = Action> {
    (state: T | undefined, action: V): T;
}
```

Comment: I always build in AOT and never had to rewrite the fat arrows ... Are you sure you don't have another issue ?

Comment: Rewriting the arrow function to an exported one also doesn't prevent you from assigning a variable in the export, does it?

    export const config: ActionReducer<ConfigModel> = function(...) {...}

Comment: @trichetriche that is strange, see here for example: https://blog.angularindepth.com/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5 or here https://github.com/ngrx/store/pull/208/files

Comment: @OClyde please add as the answer I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: added the answer, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting the arrow function to an exported one doesn't prevent you from assigning a variable in the export:

```
export const config: ActionReducer<ConfigModel> = function(state: ConfigModel = null, {type, payload}: action.ResponseActions) {
    switch (type) {
        case configAction.LOAD_SUCCESS:
            return ...;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```